# Performance difference between structs of equal size, but different number of members

Tags: c++, performance, struct

Suppose we have 2 POD structs composed of only integral data types (including enums and raw pointers).

```
struct A
{
  std::int64_t x = 0;
  std::int64_t y = 1;
};

struct B
{
  std::int64_t x = 0;
  std::int32_t y = 1;
  std::int32_t z = 2;
};
```

Note that **A** and **B** are both 128 bits in size.
Let's also assume we're on 64-bit architecture.

Of course, if `x`, `y`, and `z` weren't integral types, the cost of copy, move, construction and destruction may be different between **A** and **B** depending on the implementation details of the members.

But if we assume that `x`, `y`, and `z` are only integral types, is there any cost difference between **A** and **B** in terms of:

1. Construction
2. Copy Construction/Assignment
3. Member Access (does alignment play any role here?)

Specifically, is the copy and initialization of two side-by-side 32-bit integers universally more expensive than a single 64-bit integer?

Or is this something specific to compiler and optimization flags?

Comment: What led you to the conclusion that asking someone will be better than writing a few sample programs yourself, running them, and then accurately measuring the resulting performance with ***your*** compiler, ***your*** hardware and ***your*** operating system?  Would some results from Turbo C++ on MSDOS on a 20 year old i386 PC be more useful to you than some benchmarks on your exact hardware?

Comment: That's implementation and os dependent. e.g. if the default copy construction of that POD is implemented by simple memcopy and the size of A and B are equal size, then there shouldn't be a difference. If it is implemented by copying each member individually then there is at least on more operation to copy a member, so there would be a difference.

Comment: @t.niese That's mostly what I wanted to know. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not interested in measurements on my local machine. I'm trying to write multi-platform code, and I need to know if my assumptions are universally correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if we assume that `x`, `y`, and `z` are only integral types, is there any cost difference between `A` and `B`...

Provided that both `A` and `B` are [trivial types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) of the same size, there shouldn't be any difference in cost of construction and copying. That's because modern compilers implement [*store merging*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> `-fstore-merging`
>
> Perform merging of narrow stores to consecutive memory addresses. This pass merges contiguous stores of immediate values narrower than a word into fewer wider stores to reduce the number of instructions. This is enabled by default at `-O2` and higher as well as `-Os`.

Example code:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct A {
  std::int64_t x = 0;
  std::int64_t y = 1;
};

struct B {
  std::int64_t x = 0;
  std::int32_t y = 1;
  std::int32_t z = 2;
};

A f0(std::int64_t x, std::int64_t y) {
    return {x, y};
}

B f1(std::int64_t x, std::int32_t y, std::int32_t z) {
    return {x, y, z};
}

void g0(A);
void g1(B);

void h0(A a) { g0(a); }
void h1(B b) { g1(b); }
```

[Here is generated assembly for construction and copy](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KhveoP):

`gcc-9.2 -O3 -std=gnu++17 -march=skylake`:

```
f0(long, long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rdx, rsi
        ret
f1(long, int, int):
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-16], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-24], rdi
        vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        vpinsrd xmm0, xmm1, esi, 2
        vpinsrd xmm2, xmm0, edx, 3
        vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24], xmm2
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp-16]
        ret
h0(int, A):
        mov     rdi, rsi
        mov     rsi, rdx
        jmp     g0(A)
h1(int, B):
        mov     rdi, rsi
        mov     rsi, rdx
        jmp     g1(B)
```

`clang-9.0 -O3 -std=gnu++17 -march=skylake`:

```
f0(long, long):                                # @f0(long, long)
        mov     rdx, rsi
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
f1(long, int, int):                               # @f1(long, int, int)
        mov     rax, rdi
        shl     rdx, 32
        mov     ecx, esi
        or      rdx, rcx
        ret
h0(int, A):                               # @h0(int, A)
        mov     rdi, rsi
        mov     rsi, rdx
        jmp     g0(A)                 # TAILCALL
h1(int, B):                               # @h1(int, B)
        mov     rdi, rsi
        mov     rsi, rdx
        jmp     g1(B)                 # TAILCALL
```

Note how both structures are passed in registers in `h0` and `h1`.

However, `gcc` botches code for construction of `B` by generating unnecessary `AVX` instructions. Filed a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93897).